# How to fix 'Invalid operands to binary expression' error in C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to make a program which saves in an object, all names got from another object, for example I have `class Cheltuieli` which saves a char and I have `class Repo` which saves an array with chars from `Cheltuieli`

I've tried changing `cout << *c;` with `cout << *c->getName();` and I only get 1 letter: **p** instead of **["pizza", "pizza"]**

***Mancare.hpp***

```
#ifndef Mancare_hpp
#define Mancare_hpp

class Cheltuieli{
private:
    char* name;
public:
    Cheltuieli();
    Cheltuieli(char* n);
    ~Cheltuieli();
    void setName(char* n);
    char* getName();
};

#endif
```

***Mancare.cpp***

```
#include "Mancare.hpp"
#include <string.h>

Cheltuieli::Cheltuieli()
{
    this -> name = NULL;
}
Cheltuieli::Cheltuieli(char* n)
{
    this -> name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    strcpy(this -> name, n);
}

Cheltuieli::~Cheltuieli()
{
    if(this -> name != NULL)
    {
        delete[] this -> name;
        this -> name = NULL;
    }
}

void Cheltuieli::setName(char *n)
{
    if(this -> name)
        delete[] this -> name;
    this -> name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
    strcpy(this -> name, n);
}

char *Cheltuieli::getName()
{
    return this -> name;
}
```

```
void Repo::addElement(Cheltuieli &c)
{
    this -> cheltuieli[this -> size] = c;
    this -> size++;
}

Cheltuieli* Repo::getAll()
{
    return this -> cheltuieli;
}
```

```
char* const ps = "pizza";
Cheltuieli a = Cheltuieli(ps);

Repo n = Repo();
n.addElement(a);
n.addElement(a);

Cheltuieli* c = n.getAll();
cout << *c;
```

I get the output: **0x100503b38** with error *Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'Cheltuieli')*

Thank you!

Comment: You need at least to show the `Cheltuieli` class. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: To print `Cheltuieli` to `cout` you have to define `operator<<` in `Cheltuieli` class.

Comment: @Amadeusz Not *in* the class, but there needs to be a global overload for `operator<<` taking an output stream and a `Cheltuieli` class as arguments.

Comment: `*c->getName()` is equal to `*(c->getName())`, which is equal to `(c->getName())[0]`.

Comment: And perhaps you should [get a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read to understand why `cout << *c` won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, the `Cheltuieli` class is implementing a very small subset of what's already done in the `std::string` class - but it's incomplete, so if you do:

```
Cheltuieli orig("something");
Cheltuieli cpy = orig;
```

both `orig` and `cpy` will have a `name` member pointing at the same address because of the default copy constructor. Read about [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#rule_of_five).

Similarly, the `Repo` class seems to be implementing something close to a `std::vector`. I suggest that you don't start fiddling about with raw pointers but to use the standard classes for this. You could even make aliases for them:

```
using Cheltuieli = std::string;
using Repo = std::vector<Cheltuieli>;
```

Used like this:

```
Cheltuieli a = "pizza";
Repo n;
n.push_back(a);
n.push_back(a);

for(auto& cheltuieli : n) {
    std::cout << cheltuieli << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try overloading << operator in Cheltuieli:

```
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Cheltuieli& x)
    {
        os << x.name;
        return os;
    }
```

Comment: No `friend` declaration and `Date`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo my bad, this is the example from Microsoft msdn. Date is Cheltuieli and yes, it is friend.

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55401504/edit) the answer so it fits the question.

Comment: You need to make the friend declaration in the class and put the definition at global scope.

Comment: You can put them both in the class @TedLyngmo, but I guess it is a better practice to do as you said.

Comment: You are correct. I let my own preferences shine through. My bad. I will actually start doing them inline to remind myself of this in the future :-)